# BigQuery Pricing for Parameterized data types

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

I have 2 BQ tables `myds.mytable1(col1 string)` and `myds.mytable2(col1 string(1))`

We are storing constant "Y" and "N" values in `col1` for both the tables.

In BigQuery, will the pricing be same or will `string(1)` cost less ?

Thanks,
Santanu

Comment: The pricing will be the same, but you enforce a constraint that will prevent bad data to be stored.

Comment: @guillaume blaquiere - Thanks for the reply, it helps